# "Autocomplete off" not working in IE - ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, controls, autocomplete

Question: Is there any reason Autocomplete=off on a ASP:Textbox would not be working in IE 7?

In case this is the best term for it, the IE Autocomplete feature is that drop down list like thing that drops down from textboxes and shows you past things you have typed in.

I need the IE Autocomplete feature to not work at this point for a textbox that is part of a user control that works like an Ajax Autocomplete control.  Problem is, when the Ajax Autocomplete selection list shows up, so does the IE Autocomplete selection box. (In cases where I might double click the textbox)  I'm using this:

```
someTextbox.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.Disabled;
```

But it stills shows up.  I've tried removing the items from the IE Autocomplete, but the next time I type something in and press enter, the problem reappears. Any ideas?

Note:  The textbox is rendered with the Autocomplete=off tag when viewing the source.

Note 2:  Have tried someTextbox.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off"); also without success

*** Update, figured it out a while ago but forgot ***

```
test.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.None;
```

That actually works.  I'm not sure what the difference is though.  Suppose Ill look that up sometime.

Comment: What should test be? What if I want autocomplete to be turned off for all form data in my website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to clear out my unanswered questions that I've answered in the original post.

```
test.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.None;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be test.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.None; ?

Comment: What should test be? What if I want autocomplete to be turned off for all form data in my website?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding AUTOCOMPLETE="off" to your form tag too:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: That would stop all textboxes from having the IE Autocomplete feature, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
someTextbox.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Answer (score 1):

in Page Load

```
txtusername.AutoCompleteType = AutoCompleteType.Disabled;
```