# Auto Complete not working on IE for a asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, autocomplete

I have a simple textbox where I am trying to make the Autocomplete enable.

Example:

[image: Auto Complete working]

Works fine on Chrome and not on IE.

I even changed the settings on IE and made the AutoComplete enabled over there. But still there is no change.

Here is the code for the textbox which is inside a div tag.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSender" CssClass="span8 input-large" 
ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="255" AutoCompleteType="FirstName"/>
```

Can anyone please suggest what might be the reason behind it?

Comment: Where is code for textbox which in div tag?

Comment: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSender" CssClass="span8 input-large" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="255" AutoCompleteType="FirstName"/>

Comment: @Dnyanesh, I have tried everything which is mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241166/autocomplete-off-not-working-in-ie-asp-net, but nothing seemed to be working.

Comment: Also BTW, the question in the link is about disabling whereas mine is about enabling.. I guess these two terms are not similar or duplicate :|

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Options (Options -> Content -> AutoComplete) try to "Delete AutoComplete history".